# how to customize FBFriendPickerViewController of facebook sdk3.1

Tags: ios5.1, ios6

[image: Image shows list of friends]

I used facebook sdk 3.1 successfully in my app and added FBFriendPickerViewController as a subview on my view, it shows my friends-list and i could select one friend at a time, when i click on done button i show selected friends profile picture on my next view with pushviewcontroller now i want the same action to be performed on didselectrow instead of chechmark row and done button. Please suggest some guidelines as i need to resolve it soon... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `[friendPickerController setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO]`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker{
    self.selectedFriends = friendPicker.selection;
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! it would probably help if you added some text to your answer explaining what your code is for. Thanks for helping!

Comment: The fbcontroller calls this selector on the delegate even through it is not defined in the protocol (see: graphObjectTableSelectionDidChange).     

-(void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker{
    NSLog(@"%@", friendPicker.selection);
}

Outputs:  {
  "first_name" = snip;
  id = 123;
  "last_name" = snip;
  name = "...snip...";
  picture = {
  data =             {
    "is_silhouette" = 0;
    url = "snip";};};

Answer (score 1):

In your .h file register the  and use the code i provided above.

This will dismiss the FBfriendPicker dialog and redirect you to your previous page. Hence allowing only single selection to be made.

Hope it helps.